# How to give permission to a SharePoint Group to edit the membership of another SharePoint group (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, 2016, groups

Is there a way to give permission to a SharePoint Group to edit the membership of another SharePoint group ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the group members be able to edit permission of other group? If so, for default permission levels, you will need to grant full control.

When you edit permission level, you can find the site permission with named "Manager Permissions". It is the permission needed to assign permissions to users and groups.

[image]

For more information, please refer to this:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make the first SharePoint group as an owner (or member) of another group and set **Who can edit the membership of the group?** settings of 2nd group accordingly:

[image]